# PowerShell calling function to change the computer machine name error

Tags: windows, function, powershell, rename, wmic

```
Function ChangeName([string]$firstname, [string]$secondname)
{
    net user administrator /active:yes
    Write-Host "The new student machine name is: $firstname-S$secondname"

    wmic computersystem where name="$(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name" call rename name="$newname"
}

ChangeName "A" "B"
```

Error message:
invalid verb switch

Comment: Where have you defined $newname?

Comment: @user3545795 But `ChangeName "A" "B"` does not set the `$newname` variable anywhere. You need something like `$newname = "$firstname-$secondname"` inside the `ChangeName` function before you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the built-in `Rename-Computer` command?

Comment: I need use PowerShell 2.0

Comment: Ouch.  You really can't update to at least 3.0?  2.0 is getting a bit long in the tooth (2009).  :-)

Comment: I run in VM , how to upgrade the Powershell in VM?

Comment: Download the correct version for your OS here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 and run it. Supported OSs are Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 and higher.